# Adding fragment to Android Developer Studio's Tabbed Activity Template

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

Beginner here. Creating an app using the Android Developer Studios Tabbed Activity Template. I have two xml, the generated fragment_main.xml that comes with the template and secondtab.xml for what I want to be the second tab.

This is the code generated by the template:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
    val viewPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
    viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
    val tabs: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)

    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
```

I've been reading through the ViewPager documentation and a lot of what I can find is making this all from scratch and I'm having trouble understanding. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. How do I add my secondtab.xml to this pregenerated template so it shows up when the user clicks on the second tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours SectionsPagerAdapter `getItem` function should looks like this:

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    fm: FragmentManager
) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int) = when (position) {
        0 -> FirstTabFragment()
        1 -> SecondTabFragment()
        else -> error("Unknown")
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int) = context.resources.getString(TAB_TITLES[position])

    override fun getCount() = 2
}
```

Because by default in this template `SectionsPagerAdapter` always creates PlaceholderFragment:

```
 override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)
 }
```

But in yours case you need use two different fragments with two different xml-layouts like this:

```
class FirstTabFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.section_label)
        return root
    }
}

class SecondTabFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondtab, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.section_label)
        return root
    }
}
```

Also make sure to add:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/section_label"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
```

to the fragment xml

Comment: So I created a SecondTabFragment.kt baseed off of the PlaceholderFragment.kt file and associated it with my SecondTab.xml layout. Adapting the SectionsPagerAdapter to what you have above just returns a Fragment already added error. Is there something I need to change in the MainActivity onCreate to run this properly?

Comment: No, MainActivity onCreate stays the same. I have updated my answer with two simple fragments example and updated adapter code

Comment: I used your Fragment class code rather than a modified duplicate of the PlaceholderFragment code, and I get the same error. "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added". It throws that error with the return(when) code or when I try to return SecondTabFragment.newInstance(position + 1). Runs fine if I return FirstTabFragment.newInstance(position + 1)

Comment: Could you please show more code? I'll check my code in Android studio and it's works as expected.

Comment: The error is "Fragment already added: secondtab" It succeeds fine if this line:  val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondtab, container, false) in both classes points at fragment_main but fails if it points at any other layout. To see if it was something in my code compliating things I created a new project from the tabbed template and implemented your code. In that I get this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: root.findViewById(R.id.section_label) must not be null

Comment: Ah! Figured it out, need to make sure this is added to the xml of the second fragment and your code works great:
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

Comment: app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />